# Gitlab runner has SSL errors connecting to the Gitlab repo (err: self signed cert in certificate chain). Suspecting Gitlab renewed its SSL CERT today

Tags: ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We have custom gitlab runner configured on our premises.
Today all the gitlab CI jobs fail with the following error:
`fatal: unable to access https://gitlab.com/username/reponame.git/: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain`

I suspect the Gitlab.com, which renewed its certificate today (Dec 14th, 2023) at midnight.
Any way we can force this new certificate to be delivered to the runner without disabling SSL check and without killing the runner and creating a new one?

Thanks.

Comment: The certificate for gitlab.com is fine. There is nothing to force to deliver here, certificates are not cached by the client. There must be another problem.

Comment: Thanks, I am not saying they have bad certificate or something like that. The problem is definitely on my end. I suspect this (cert renewal) as a cause, because yesterday it was working, now it does not, and their certificate was updated exactly last midnight.

Comment: I experienced the same problem today. I was able to fix it by restarting the runners.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue since yesterday - in my case the problem was easily solved by just updating system packages on the runner instance (including the version of the gitlab-runner package). I am not sure if it was the package itself or system-level CA certs, but whichever it was a simple `apt update && apt upgrade` helped - hope it also does for you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, restarting the runner did not help; host packages update was not enough as well.
I had to remove the runner from gitlab, update both gitlab-runner and docker dind images to the latest and re-register the runner.
It works now.